# SVG Background - Add animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

```
HTML

<label class="svgCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" checked="checked" class="svgCheckboxOn">
    <span>
        ::before
        ::after
    </span>
</label>



CSS

.svgCheckbox > input[type=checkbox] + span:before {
content: ' ';
position: absolute;
left: -35px;
top: -3px;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
display: block;
background: #FCFCFC;
border: 2px solid #b1bac1;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.svgCheckbox > input[type=checkbox] + span:after {
content: ' ';
position: absolute;
left: -35px;
top: -3px;
width: 23px;
height: 23px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
transition: all .2s ease;
transform: scale(0);
opacity: 0;
}

.svgCheckbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:after {
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1;
}
```

Currently the only animation that I could think of that I can use is scale. Is it possible to use this technique however to have animation like in link below.

https://codepen.io/tingc10/pen/ZbVMBe/

I need to use the background technique as all the others one were causing problem in internet explorer.

Comment: also note you have four ticks in the svg ... consider using this instead: `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg width='1040' height='810' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23373737' d='M1025.3 124.5l-113-113c-8.6-8.6-24-8.6-34.3 0L371 518.3 158.8 306c-8.6-8.6-24-8.6-34.3 0l-113 113c-8.6 8.6-8.6 24 0 34.3l231.2 231.2 113 113c8.6 8.6 24 8.6 34.3 0l113-113 524-524c7-10.3 7-25.7-1.6-36z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");` though at the size you are using can simplify and remove the rounded corners ... icomoon likely has a free tick icon you could use

Comment: This sort-of works for me on chrome ... if I set the `left: -35` to a positive number (otherwise it is hidden off-page). If you have not read it yet look at https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/